# Trouble starting resource manager in CDH5 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS ,single node implementation

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, hadoop-yarn, httpserver, cloudera-cdh, resourcemanager

I am trying to install CDH5 (cloudera) on a single node(64-bit machine) running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have successfully installed hdfs (namenode and datanode are running fine). After configuring all the properties for deploying yarn, when I try to start resource manager or node manager it gives gives following errors:

> ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Returning, interrupted : java.lang.InterruptedException
>   2015-06-29 14:02:44,265 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
>   2015-06-29 14:02:44,264 INFO 
>  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.ContainerAllocationExpirer thread interrupted
>   2015-06-29 14:02:44,265 INFO
>  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
>   2015-06-29 14:02:44,265 FATAL
>  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: **Error starting ResourceManager
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: Error starting http server** 
>   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:278)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startWepApp(ResourceManager.java:983) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1083)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1215)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: **Problem in starting http server. Server handlers failed**
>       at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:841)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:273)
>       ... 4 more

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: This hadoop bug appears to be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11754 -- not sure on a fix w/out this patch though